# Issue with installing SDL2 using CLion and vcpkg

Tags: c++, sdl-2, vcpkg

```
====================[ Build | main | Debug ]====================================
C:\Users\Amund\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\Amund\Desktop\main\cmake-build-debug --target main -j 14
[1/1] Linking CXX executable main.exe
FAILED: main.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Amund\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.obj -o main.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libmain.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/manual-link/SDL2maind.lib  vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/SDL2d.lib -lshell32  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\Amund\Desktop\main\cmake-build-debug && C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file C:/Users/Amund/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary C:/Users/Amund/Desktop/main/cmake-build-debug/main.exe -installedDir C:/Users/Amund/Desktop/main/cmake-build-debug/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/bin -OutVariable out""
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
C:\Users\Amund\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/manual-link/SDL2maind.lib(CMakeFiles/SDL2main.dir/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x290): undefined reference to `_RTC_CheckStackVars'
C:\Users\Amund\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/manual-link/SDL2maind.lib(CMakeFiles/SDL2main.dir/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c.obj):(.rtc$IMZ+0x0): undefined reference to `_RTC_InitBase'
C:\Users\Amund\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/manual-link/SDL2maind.lib(CMakeFiles/SDL2main.dir/src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c.obj):(.rtc$TMZ+0x0): undefined reference to `_RTC_Shutdown'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

for it to compile without the errors listed

Comment: The `x64-windows` triplet shown in your output: `vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib` folder builds binaries for msvc which are incompatible with MinGW which you are using here: `C:\Users\Amund\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe` There are MinGW triplets that in vcpkg. You need to use those to build for MinGW.

Comment: I did not see it was building for msvc, thought vcpkg would get the right sdl2 version. I am going to try using ur suggestion

Comment: How did you compile / install the `vcpkg` package?

Comment: BTW the error about _RTC is described here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/33012350/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33012350/487892)

Answer (score 1):

The `x64-windows` triplet shown in your output: `vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/debug/lib` folder builds binaries for msvc which are mostly incompatible with MinGW for c++ based code. You are using MinGW here: `C:\Users\Amund\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe` There are MinGW triplets that in vcpkg. You need to use those to build for MinGW.

[vcpkg with MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63031513/vcpkg-with-mingw)

Comment: If mingw was installed with MSYS2, you can use MSYS2's package manager to install a compatible version of many libraries, [including SLD2](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2)